# Разборать масив json

Tags: php, json

Есть json:

```
[{"product_id":"1779","name":"\u0421\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e AR-003 \u043a\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043a \u0431\u0435\u043b\u044b\u0439","model":"008333440","option":[],"quantity":"1","price":"290 \u0440.","total":"290 \u0440.","href":"url"},{"product_id":"1809","name":"\u041a\u0430\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0434\u043b\u044f iPhone 5\/6 Remax LESU RC-050i 1m \u0427\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439","model":"\u0423\u0422-00000864","option":[],"quantity":"1","price":"490 \u0440.","total":"490 \u0440.","href":"url"}]
```

Я данный json декодирую

```
$json ='[{"product_id":"1779","name":"\u0421\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e AR-003 \u043a\u0443\u0431\u0438\u043a \u0431\u0435\u043b\u044b\u0439","model":"008333440","option":[],"quantity":"1","price":"290 \u0440.","total":"290 \u0440.","href":"url"},{"product_id":"1809","name":"\u041a\u0430\u0431\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0434\u043b\u044f iPhone 5\/6 Remax LESU RC-050i 1m \u0427\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439","model":"\u0423\u0422-00000864","option":[],"quantity":"1","price":"490 \u0440.","total":"490 \u0440.","href":"url"}]';
$json = substr($json, 1, -1);
$obj = json_decode($json);

$json = substr($json, 1, -1);
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'name'}; // 12345
```

Но у меня их два в массиве, как разобрать на части что бы например продукт было
1779, 1809 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас хороший json, не надо его портить

```
// $json = substr($json, 1, -1);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

получаете массив из двух объектов: `$obj[0]` первый продукт, `$obj[1]` второй

Если хотите работать с массивами, добавьте второй параметр `$obj = json_decode($json, True);`

Comment: сделал так, print $obj->[0]{'product_id'};
выходит ошибка

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76905fafb0676409bba780a53f1362db7ab3c0c9

Comment: оно работает когда сам добавил json, но у меня он берется из бд по этому я делаю так и убираю квадратные скобки

Comment: когда вы уберете квадратные скобки, json станет не валидным, decode вернет False

Comment: спасибо, а что делать если не знаешь количество?

Comment: Сделайте цикл по объектам, каждый последовательно обработайте. count($obj) - даст количество